# SQL error I can't figure this out

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE pa_adclicks(
bannerid mediumint( 9 ) NOT NULL default '0',
zoneid mediumint( 9 ) NOT NULL default '0',
t_stamptimestamp( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
host varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
source varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL default '',
countrychar( 2 ) NOT NULL default '',
KEY bannerid_date( bannerid, t_stamp ) ,
KEY date( t_stamp ) ,
KEY zoneid( zoneid )
) ENGINE = 'MyISAM';
```

MySQL said:

> Error#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
>         host varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
>         source varchar(50) NOT' at line 14

Comment: Please show your complete query.

Comment: Show the query. Possibly an attempt to use the length `(14)` on a type that doesn't support it.

Comment: You are showing us a snippet of a code that wouldn't work, instead of your whole code, how are we supposed to know what is wrong with it?

Comment: i have upload some file to my phpmyadmin however there should be more file i think        Structure epay_area_list
    Structure epay_faq_cat_list
    Structure epay_faq_list
    Structure epay_hold
    Structure epay_notes
    Structure epay_safetransfers
    Structure epay_shops
    Structure epay_signups
    Structure epay_subscribers
    Structure epay_subscriptions
    Structure epay_templates
    Structure epay_transactions
    Structure epay_users
    Structure epay_visitors
    Structure pa_acls

Answer (score 3):

I'll try again - you have no space in between `t_stamp` and `timestamp` in  `t_stamptimestamp( 14 ) NOT NULL`.