# sql file error message

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL error I can’t figure this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147356/sql-error-i-cant-figure-this-out)

```
#
# Table structure for table `pa_adclicks`
#
CREATE TABLE pa_adclicks(
bannerid mediumint( 9 ) NOT NULL default '0',
zoneid mediumint( 9 ) NOT NULL default '0',
t_stamptimestamp( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
host varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
source varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL default '',
countrychar( 2 ) NOT NULL default '',
KEY bannerid_date( bannerid, t_stamp ) ,
KEY date( t_stamp ) ,
KEY zoneid( zoneid )
) ENGINE = 'MyISAM';
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(14) NOT NULL,   host varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',   source
>   varchar(50) NOT' at line 14

Comment: He's figured out how to ask questions, but maybe not how to read answers.

Comment: does anyone know how to fix this file willing to pay too many errors for i have some table uploaded to my phpadmin but im not sure how many i am missing and my site still cant connect to the server

Comment: thats funny Isemi your probably right

Comment: In English youcan sticktwo wordstogether and stillunderstand. In SQL you can't. Your SQL file is damaged, possibly due to cut-and-paste that removed tabs. All your errors come from that. It is always the same error: no need of posting a new question for each one! Read below, Catcall has the answer you need.

Comment: Willing to pay!? Send me one BILLION dollars . . .

Answer (score 2):

The following line seems to have two errors.

```
t_stamptimestamp( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
```

You might be able to correct it like this.

```
t_stamp timestamp NOT NULL ,
```

If you're not intimately familiar with MySQL, you should probably skim the details of the [data types datetime and timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html).

There's a similar error farther down. I'm sure you can find it.